# MSVC initialization of heap when padding is involved

Tags: c++, memory-management, heap-memory, msvcrt

The MSVC memory manager has certain hexidecimal codes it uses in debug builds to mark memory depending on what operation was performed. These are documented [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_number_%28programming%29#Magic_debug_values).

In particular, the code 0xCDCDCDCD is used to mark allocated but uninitialized heap memory. Suppose I have the following structure:

```
struct Test
{
   bool foo;
   int value;

   Test() : foo(false), value(0) {}
};
```

When I allocate this object, will my memory look like this (note that I am writing out the hexidecimal bytes as they would appear in-order, endianness hasn't been considered for this example)?

`00 CD CD CD CD 00 00 00 00`

Above, `00 CD CD CD` represents the 4-byte aligned boolean. The last 3 bytes are `0xCD` because the memory manager initialized those values to CD, however the actual initialization of that boolean in the structure only touches 1 byte since a boolean represents only 1 byte on my machine.

Is this the correct behavior?

Comment: Just curious - why are you asking? And why haven't you just checked?

Comment: I'm asking because I'm having an alignment issue and I'm seeing the value `00 CD CD CD` where one of my boolean members are and I just want to confirm that the program is only initializing the first byte of the four. If this is the case then I can explain why the last 3 bytes are 0xCD

Comment: @Robert, You shouldn't make any decision based on the contents of the alignment part as it's implmentation defined and can contain any random data.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just try it.  Make sure to compile with `/MDd` or the like to link to the debug runtime.  (The answer is yes in VS2010).

Comment: Looking at behavior in the Debug build is not a good strategy.  The unusual stuff happens when the optimizer kicks in.

Comment: @Hans, it is implementation-defined and MSVC's memory pattern filling only happens in the debug runtime.  The behavior will be the same in an optimized build.  The debug runtime library binaries aren't going to change just because the user's code is compiled optimized if he still links to the debug runtime.

Answer (score 1):

There's nothing that would stop the code generator from writing 4 bytes if that produces faster code.  Or use memset(), a common optimization in the MSVC compiler.  But that obviously didn't happen.  Either way is correct, reading the structure padding is undefined behavior.